# Scope and Usage of Nested Classes

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm writing some code that interfaces with a GPS receiver and I'm trying to understand if the way I'm attempting to implement it is possible and if so how to do it.

The GPS communicates with an Arduino via I2C and I want to have a single object that handles all of the GPS interface commands. The basic structure is as follows:

Header File (Simplified)

```
//UBLOX.h
class UBLOX_INTERFACE
{
     private:
          const uint8_t i2cAddress;
     public:
          UBLOX_INTERFACE(uint8_t address);

     class NMEA
     {
          private:    
          void intakeNMEA(); //This function needs access to UBLOX_INTERFACE::i2cAddress
          //Other local variables and functions
     };

     class UBX_COMMS
     {
      private:
      uint8_t prepAndSendPacket(uint8_t packet[], const uint16_t packetLength);

      public:
      UBX_COMMS(uint8_t ubxclass, uint8_t id, uint8_t length0, uint8_t length1);
     };


    class UBX_CFG_RATE : public UBX_COMMS
    {
        using UBX_COMMS::UBX_COMMS;

    private:
    public:
        bool set(const uint16_t GNSSmeasureRate); // Sets GNSS measurement rate
        void poll();
    };


    class UBX_CFG_RST : public UBX_COMMS
    {
        using UBX_COMMS::UBX_COMMS;

    private:
    public:
        bool gnssReset(const uint8_t navBbrMask);
        bool hardwareReset(const uint8_t resetMode);
    };
}
```

CPP File (Simplified)

```
//UBLOX.cpp

#include "UBLOX.h"

//UBLOX_INTERFACE Class Functions
UBLOX_INTERFACE::UBLOX_INTERFACE(uint8_t address): i2cAddress(address)
{
    NMEA nmea;
    UBX_CFG_RATE ubxCFG_RATE(0x06, 0x08, 0, 6); //These values are permanently defined constants for each command type 
    UBX_CFG_RST ubxCFG_RST(0x06, 0x04, 0, 4);
}


//NMEA Class Functions
void UBLOX_INTERFACE::NMEA::intakeNMEA()
{

    Wire.beginTransmission(i2cAddress); //This line has a compile error: invalid use of non-static data member 'UBLOX_INTERFACE::i2cAddress'
    //There's a whole bunch more after this but not relevant to this question
}



//UBX_COMMS Class Functions
UBLOX_INTERFACE::UBX_COMMS::UBX_COMMS(uint8_t ubxclass, uint8_t id, uint8_t length0, uint8_t length1) : classByte(ubxclass), idByte(id), payloadLength{length0, length1}, stdPacketLength(packetLengthCalc(length0, length1)){};


uint8_t UBLOX_INTERFACE::UBX_COMMS::prepAndSendPacket(uint8_t packet[], const uint16_t packetLength)
{
    calcAndInsertUBXChecksum(packet, packetLength);
    Wire.beginTransmission(i2cAddress); //error: invalid use of non-static data member 'UBLOX_INTERFACE::i2cAddress'

    Wire.write(packet, packetLength);
    uint8_t errorCode = Wire.endTransmission();
    return errorCode;
}



// UBX_CFG_RATE Class Functions
     //definition of UBLOX_INTERFACE::UBX_CFG_PRT::setPort() and UBLOX_INTERFACE::UBX_CFG_PRT::poll()

// UBX_CFG_RST Class Functions
     //definition of UBLOX_INTERFACE::UBX_CFG_RST::gnssReset() and UBLOX_INTERFACE::UBX_CFG_PRT::hardwareReset()
```

Example of how I *want* to use this

```
void main()
{
     UBLOX_INTERFACE u;

     u.ubxCFG_RST.hardwareReset();
     u.ubxCFG_RATE.set(SOME SETTINGS HERE);

     while(true)
     {
          u.nmea.intakeNMEA();
     }
}
```

The real code I'm working with does not compile. Currently I'm getting errors in all of the subclasses where I attempt to use the `UBLOX_INTERFACE::i2cAddress` function: `error: invalid use of non-static data member 'UBLOX_INTERFACE::i2cAddress'` If I change the `i2cAddress` to be static, then I get a different error saying I have to use a non-static variable in the class construction. And on top of that, I'm unsure if my method of initializing the subclasses within the parent class constructor is even valid. Can anyone explain if this method is valid or what I should be doing instead?

Comment: If you only want a single instance, perhaps `UBLOX_INTERFACE` should be a namespace instead of a class (with no members)? That way you could hide the address variable in the .cpp file.

Comment: I like that idea, had not thought of that. But I was hoping to keep a single object reference so that you didn't have to create an NMEA and all of the UBX objects separately in main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `i2cAddress` from the class `NMEA` but you have defined the variable in the class `UBLOX_INTERFACE`.

The classes might be defined inside each other, but the instances of the classes does not have access to eachothers variable.

Alternatives would be to either make `i2cAddress` static, or global or to send a pointer or copy of `i2cAddress` or to `UBLOX_INTERFACE` to the class `NMEA` at some point.

Or depending on your code (i do understand it fully), you might want to put `i2cAddress` as a member variable of `NMEA`, that would also solve the problem.

---

Edit:

If you want to initialize a static member variable in the constructor, it is not possible to do it in the *initializer list*

```cpp
//UBLOX_INTERFACE Class Functions
UBLOX_INTERFACE::UBLOX_INTERFACE(uint8_t address) // not here :
{
    i2cAddress = address; // This should work

    // The following variables does only exist in this function,
    // I think that you might want to move these to the function body
    // instead
    NMEA nmea;
    UBX_CFG_RATE ubxCFG_RATE(0x06, 0x08, 0, 6); //These values are permanently defined constants for each command type 
    UBX_CFG_RST ubxCFG_RST(0x06, 0x04, 0, 4);
}
```

And about if it would be possible to initialize like classes like you do: No I dont think it works like it does now. You need to add the classes as class members, and then initialize them in the initialize list like you previously did with i2cAddress.

Comment: I had `i2cAddress` as a member of `UBLOX_INTERFACE` only because it was used in both the `NMEA` and `UBX` subclasses. And I did try and make `i2cAddress` static but then I got a error at the `UBLOX_INTERFACE` constructor: `error: 'const uint8_t UBLOX_INTERFACE::i2cAddress' is a static data member; it can only be initialized at its definition`.

If I were to also make `i2cAddress` a member of the `NMEA` and `UBX` subclasses, I would want to initialize the subclasses in the `UBLOX_INTERFACE` constructor (as I do now with  `ubxCFG_RATE` and `ubxCFG_RS`). Is this concept in general valid?

Comment: @Brendan I updated according to your question

Comment: @Brendan would you mind marking the answer as accepted?